# Módulos builtin en Python

Tags: python

Estoy empezando a aprender Python y me surge una duda metódica sobre la documentación oficial. En concreto he empezado a documentarme sobre las librerías de manejo de fecha y hora. La primera crítica que me gustaría hacer a la documentación es que no se indica que el módulo `time` sea un módulo builtin. Y en relación con esto, mi pregunta es la siguiente:

- La documentación de Python no debería incluir sólo la información de los módulos, clases, funciones, etc. propios del sistema (builtin)? Porque, en mi opinión, todo lo demás son constructos que no forman parte del sistema en sí, y que cualquiera podría rehacer a su gusto o hacerlo de otra forma. Entonces, por qué el resto de librerías, como DateTime, etc. son incluidas en la documentación como parte del lenguaje?

Si les parece que mi pregunta no tiene sentido les ruego que entiendan que soy principiante en esto.  Muchas gracias por su atención. Un saludo.

Comment: Aunque toda la librería estándar está en la documentación de python, no está "como parte del lenguaje" como dices, sino en una sección separada. La documentación tiene dos secciones claramente separadas: documentación del lenguaje y documentación de la biblioteca estándar. El hecho de que ambas formen parte de la documentación oficial es porque cuando instalas python inseparablemente instalas ambas cosas (un intérprete del lenguaje y la biblioteca estándar), salvo en implementaciones muy particulares como micropython que tiene su propia documentación,

Comment: Comprendo. Muy amable, Abulafia, muchas gracias por la aclaración. Perdóname una pregunta: por qué no has puesto tu comentario como respuesta, en lugar de como comentario?

Comment: Pues no sé... cuando me cabe en un comentario considero que quizás no tenga entidad suficiente como respuesta :-) Pero si quieres lo convierto en respuesta,  y lo expando un poco más

Comment: No es necesario, gracias. Es sólo que pensé que si fuera respuesta se podría votar, pero veo que los comentarios también se pueden. Soy nuevo por aquí, y aún ando un poco perdido.